# How do I wire these potentiometers?

Tags: components, potentiometer, pinout

I'm trying to make [this circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5ojU.gif) (components in question are `R10` and `R11`).  I have two really nice sliders I bought from Science + Surplus.  Problem is, I'm a teensy bit confused on how to wire even regular pots - and these ones have eight (8!) pins each.  I think they're dual-gang sliders for stereo systems, but I can't for the life of me pick out the three connections I should be making.  Which are my left/right/wiper pins (or how can I find out)?

The sliders in question:[image: front view][image]

Comment: Sorry for the giant images :(

Comment: Use an ohmmeter to find out how the pins are mapped.

Comment: Do they click anywhere?

Comment: @Passerby they're smooth all the way through.

Comment: Then I have no idea why the extra 2 pins. Maybe redundant, connected to other points? Anyway if you have the pot pins you needed, you could ignore them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an Ohm Meter, measure any two pins until you get a reading of 10kΩ. Those will be the two far ends of that pot. Then picking any of those two pins to keep one of your meter leads on, measure a third pin, while changing the slide around. If you get a measurement on it that changes accordingly, you have found the wiper for that pot. Repeat for the pins of the second pot.

Comment: It is likely that the wiper contact is connected at both ends to two pins and the resistance terminals are adjacent. The wiper pins should read close to zero ohms from end to end.